# Angular js load local json array

Tags: json, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am new in angular js and ionic 
I am trying to retreive the date (data that i want to retreive it) from an array and repeat it on html file
knowing  that my array was stored in local storage under the name of List like :

```
List: {
    error: false,
    List_issue: [
        0: {
            id: 16
            tittle "doggie"
            image: ""
            date: "2015-08-17 2:22:24 p.m."
        },
        1: {
            id: 17
            tittle "mmmmm"
            image: ""
            date: "2015-08-18 2:22:24 p.m."
        }
    ]
}
```

how can i do it ?? please help me

Comment: That isn't json, it is missing proper quotes and `List` shouldn't be there. Use http://jsonlint.com as a validator. Not 100% clear what you are asking either

Comment: "how can I do it ??" isn't a proper question.  Your statement says that you are trying to repeat the data in HTML, but you didn't list any HTML at all.  I suspect that you should read up on [`ng-repeat`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat#!), and then come back and edit the question with a specific problem.

Comment: the problem that i dont know how to retreive the data "date" from the array  in my controller, and as i said i m beginner

Comment: I would start here if your a beginner, this will get the basic under your belt:https://www.codecademy.com/learn  take the angular js course. It is a good place to start and learn syntax and basic angular ways of doing things

Comment: Thanks a lot  @Jess Patton

Answer (score 0):

The JSON format is wrong in your code, update the JSON as in your controller as

```
$scope.lists = [{
            id: 16,
            tittle :"doggie",
            image: "",
            date: "2015-08-17 2:22:24 p.m."
        },
        {
            id: 17,
            tittle :"mmmmm",
            image: "",
            date: "2015-08-18 2:22:24 p.m."
        }
];
```

And in your html the code to print the Dates as

```
<ion-list>
 <ion-item ng-repeat = "list in lists">
   {{list.date}}
 </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Anil kumar